# How to do a strsplit on percentages in R

Tags: regex, r, string, substring, strsplit

From this string `border-color:#002449;left:74.4%top;37%;` I would like to make the first percentage `74.4%` a variable called `X` and the second percentage `37%` a variable called `Y`.

I can compelete this with a str_extract and regex but I would rather create the variables `X` and `Y` by doing a strsplit.

What I am currently doing:

```
coord <- str_extract_all(s, "\\d+(\\.\\d+){0,1}%")[[1]]

X <- coord[1] ; Y <- coord[2]
```

This works fine, but my data.frame currently has 54 rows in it not just 1. I believe doing a strsplit will be better.

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if any further information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rbind` the `coord`

```
library(stringr)
coord <- str_extract_all(s, "\\d+(\\.\\d+){0,1}%")
d1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, coord), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Another option with `str_extract` would be

```
coord <- str_extract_all(s, "\\d+(?:%)")
d2 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, coord), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

---

With `strsplit`, we could try

```
coord <- lapply(strsplit(s, '[0-9.]+%(*SKIP)(*F)|.', 
                     perl=TRUE), setdiff, "")
d3 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, coord), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

#### data

```
s <- "border-color:#002449;left:74.4%top;37%;"
```